# Почему при объединении под одним циклом for парсинг останавливается?

Tags: python, requests, bs4

Если парсить названия, цены и urlы в отдельных циклах for из разных мест (soup.findAll), то все работает как надо, но при объединении в один цикл - останавливается после получения одного значения из каждой категории, что я делаю не так?

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

# содержимое страницы
site = soup.findAll('main', class_='site-main hfeed')

data = []
for i in site:
    name = i.find('h2', class_='woocommerce-loop-product__title').text
    price = i.find('span', class_='woocommerce-Price-amount amount').text.replace(u'\xa0₽', '')
    url = i.find('a', class_='woocommerce-LoopProduct-link woocommerce-loop-product__link').get('href')
    data.append([name, price, url])

print(data)
```

Comment: А вы уверены, что на странице тегов main больше чем один?

Comment: print(site) отдает всю нужную информацию и значит в цикл for она поступает вся.

Comment: Это не имеет значения. Повторяю, вы уверены, что на странице тегов main больше чем один? Если вдруг он всё-таки один, то и длина списка site будет 1 — значит и цикл выполнится один раз и вы с таким кодом никогда не получите больше одного значения.

Comment: Да, действительно, с "site = soup.findAll('li', class_='product') заработало как надо". Оформите как ответ, я думаю я не один такой чайник. Спасибо! :)